# Is AsyncStorage still remain after update app to new codebase?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a `react-native` project that I plan to re-write all the code base, new source code. And I plan to use the same package id.

So my client, they want the users will receive notification about new app version. And after they updated, **the login state will remain** , so users will not have to login again.

So I wonder in this case, AsyncStorage has been clear or it should remain ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the user does not uninstall the app and installs it again, the AsyncStorage will not be cleared. Taking into account that the app will be deployed to the same Android/IOS app in Play Store/App Store.

Comment: Yes, I will have the account of this app. Thank you. Have you been through this situation?

Comment: Yes of course, me and my team already been through big updates were we refactored a great part of the code. There are only a few situations were AsyncStorage gets delete: 1 - when the user uninstalls the app 2- when the user clears the app cache 3 - when you force it in your code with AsyncStorage.clear(), which in my case, I do every time a user logouts

Comment: Will you accept this answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: Here someone asks the same question but he states the opposite though: The storage is cleared after an auto-update (no uninstall):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616473/auto-updated-app-cause-the-asyncstorage-auto-reset/70811157#70811157

What do you all think? I am also interested to understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that my AsyncStorage values have reset after a straight app update which didn't seem to be happening in the past. could be some bugs on specific version