# Auto updated App cause the AsyncStorage auto reset?

Tags: reactjs, asyncstorage

I uploaded react native app ( android version ) ver 1.0 to Play store. Then i uploaded new version 1.1 to Play store.
After App is auto updated to new version 1.1, keys/values in AsyncStorage is auto clear. Is it a correct behavior ? My understanding is AsyncStorage will be cleared if uninstalled/ installed app only. i used "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" library. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is AsyncStorage still remain after update app to new codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221027/is-asyncstorage-still-remain-after-update-app-to-new-codebase)

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer here:
[Is AsyncStorage still remain after update app to new codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221027/is-asyncstorage-still-remain-after-update-app-to-new-codebase)

But the answer states the opposite of what you experienced here.

Maybe you want to state that there too? It seems that something may not be the same in all cases.